# How to add a new column to one snowflake table from another snowflake table based on two join keys from databricks notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I have data I've pulled from a S3 bucket and placed into a pyspark dataframe, this data has a few columns of interest: `user_id`, `user_sign_up_dt`, `special_data`. Inside my databricks notebook I make a sf connection string like so:

```
my_df.write.format("snowflake") \
    .option("sfurl", "some_url") \
    .option("sfuser", "some_user") \
    .option("sfpassword", "some_pwd") \
    .option("sfdatabase", "some_db") \
    .option("sfwarehouse", "some_warehouse") \
    .option("role", "some_role") \
    .option("dbtable", "some_table") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save()
```

Once I run that above code, I can then go into sf and see that table has been generated.

Now I have a pre-existing table in snowflake that I would like to add data from "some_table" to, call it "other_table".

What I've tried doing is making another connection to snowflake and then make two temp tables based on the two tables that are now in sf then join on the shared column: "user_id", "user_sign_up_dt" like so:

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
user = "some_user",
password = "some_password",
account = "some_account",
warehouse = "some_warehouse",
database = "some_database",
schema = "some_schema"
_

# then to make the two temp tables:
OTHER_TABLE = spark.read.format("snowflake) \
...
# same set up as before except load

OTHER_TABLE.createOrReplaceTempView("OTHER_TABLE_tmp")

SOME_TABLE = spark.read.format("snowflake") \
...

# same set up
SOME_TABLE.createOrReplaceTempView("SOME_TABLE_tmp")
```

Now that I have two temp tables I join on them and load that data into OTHER_TABLE.

```
join_query = """
MERGE INTO OTHER_TABLE_tmp
USING SOME_TABLE_tmp
ON OTHER_TABLE_tmp.user_id = SOME_TABLE_tmp.user_id
AND OTHER_TABLE_tmp.user_sign_up_dt = SOME_TABLE_tmp.user_sign_up_dt
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET OTHER_TABLE_tmp.special_data = SOME_TABLE_tmp.special_data
"""

spark.sql(join_query)
```

This doesn't work and I get the following exception:

> `AnalysisException: cannot resolve OTHER_TABLE_tmp.special_data in MERGE command given columnns [OTHER_TABLE_tmp.acct_dt, OTHER_TABLE_tmp.active_accts...]`

Is there a more effective way to do this inside of databricks?

Thank you